# userInterfaceLayoutDirection not updating when semanticContentAttribute is set

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to override the `semanticContentAttribute` and force the layout to render from right to left for Arabic by using `UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft`.

The layout changes, but if I try getting the current layout, it returns the wrong one (left to right). Also, the text alignments don't change despite the `textAlignment` being set to `.natural` as well.

`UIView.userInterfaceLayoutDirection` is used to check the current interface layout direction as follows -

`UIView.userInterfaceLayoutDirection(for: self.view.semanticContentAttribute)`. (this returns left-to-right after I've overridden it to right-to-left)

Is this expected, or am I doing something wrong?

PS: I'm using trailing and leading edges for all the constraints, and setting `semanticContentAttribute` before the views are initialized.